# Cfengine reporting files deployed

Tags: cfengine

Hi I'm testing out cfengine deploys in rhel 5.6. Everything works great but I am wondering if there is a way for the community edition of cfengine to report to a file all the files it has deployed to a system. I deploy all files from a policy host via secure cp.  I'm using cfengine3 community edition.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is old, but there was no answer ...

This may be possible in the Nova edition. If you want to cobble something together with the community edition I think what you would need to do is define a class if repaired, or always whatever depending what kind of report your looking to get for that file, then have a report to file based on that class existence.

```
vars:
    "etc_profile" string => "/var/cfengine/distrib/etc/profile";
files:
    "/etc/profile"
        copy_from => secure_cp("$(etc_profile)", "$(sys.policy_hub)"),
        classes   => if_repaired("distributed_etc_profile"),
        comment   => "Get /etc/profile from distribution server, and define class when distributed so we can report on it";

reports:
    distributed_etc_profile::
        "$(sys.date) $(sys.host) /etc/profile",
            report_to_file => "/tmp/received_file_from_dist";
```

If you want it collected back to a central point, thats also something you would have to orchestrate. You mgiht want to just post that file to a webdav server so you dont have to have each host defined in the central servers policy to do a copy from.

Anyway, I know the answer is long overdue, but I hope it helps.